# Showing and hiding article elements with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am almost done with an exercise but need help with the last bit. The premise is to have only a clicked article to be shown out of a list of four articles. I can hide all but the first article and get the heading to show when the respective article is clicked but I'm having trouble with the code to get the actual article to show. Here is an HTML snippet (let me know if you need more):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sorkin").hide();
  $("#chua").hide();
  $("#sampson").hide();
  $("article").hide();
  $("h1:first-child").next("article").show();

  $("a").click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr("href");
    
    if (id != $("article").prev("h1 a").attr("href")) {
      $("h1 a").hide();
      $("article").hide();
    };
    
    $(id).show();
    $("id").next("article").show();
  });
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<h1><a id="toobin">The Supreme Nine: Black Robed Secrets</a></h1>
<article>   
  <img src="images/toobin_court.jpg" alt="Jeffrey Toobin">
  <h2>October<br>Jeffrey Toobin</h2>
  <p>Author of the critically acclaimed best seller, The Nine: Inside the Secret World of the 
  Supreme Court, Jeffrey Toobin brings the inside story of one of America's most mysterious 
  and powerful institutions to the Saroyan stage. At the podium, Toobin is an unbiased, deeply 
  analytic expert on American law, politics and procedure and he provides a unique look into the 
  inner workings of the Supreme Court and its influence.</p>
  <p>Inside the Secret World of the Supreme Court was published by Doubleday and spent more than 
  four months on the NY Times best-seller list, earning Toobin the 2008 J. Anthony Lukas Prize 
  for Nonfiction from the Columbia Graduate School of Journalism. Toobin has also written several 
  other best-selling books, including A Vast Conspiracy: The Real Story of the Sex Scandal that 
  Nearly Brought Down a President; The Run of His Life: The People vs. O.J. Simpson; and 
  Too Close to Call: The 36-Day Battle to Decide the 2000 Election.</p>
  <p>Jeffrey Toobin joined CBB from ABC News, where, during his six-year tenure as a legal analyst, 
  he provided legal views on the nation's most provocative and high profile cases, including the O.J. 
  Simpson civil trial and the Kenneth Starr investigation of the Clinton White House. Toobin 
  received a 2001 Emmy Award for his coverage of the Elian Gonzales custody saga.</p>
  <p>Toobin is a staff writer at The New Yorker and has been covering legal affairs for the magazine 
  since 1993. He has written articles on such subjects as Attorney General John Ashcroft, the 2001 
  dispute over Florida's votes for president, the Paula Jones sexual harassment case, and Supreme 
  Court Justice Clarence Thomas.</p>
  <p>Currently a senior analyst for CNN Worldwide, Toobin is based in the network's New York bureau. 
  He graduated from Harvard magna cum laude with a Bachelor of Arts degree in 1982 and earned a 
  Truman scholarship. He is also a 1986 magna cum laude graduate of Harvard Law School, where he 
  was an editor of the Harvard Law Review.</p>
  <p><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>
</article>
<h1><a id="sorkin">The Politics of <em>Too Big to Fail</em></a></h1>
<article>
  <img src="images/sorkin_desk260.jpg" alt="Andrew Ross Sorkin"/>
  <h2>November<br>Andrew Ross Sorkin</h2>
  <p><em>New York Times</em> columnist and author, Andrew Ross Sorkin, 
  has been described as &ldquo;the most famous financial journalist of his generation.&rdquo;  
  A leading voice on Wall Street and corporate America, his <em>New York Times</em> bestseller, 
  <em>Too Big to Fail: The Inside Story of How Wall Street and Washington Fought to Save 
  the Financial System—and Themselves</em>, was the first true, behind-the-scenes, 
  moment-by-moment account of how that financial crisis developed into a global tsunami.</p>
  <p><em>The Economist</em>, <em>The Financial Times</em> and <em>Business Week</em> all named 
  <em>Too Big To Fail</em> one of the best books of the year.  The book was published by 
  Viking October 20, 2009. The book was adapted as a movie by HBO Films and premiered on HBO on 
  May 23, 2011. The film was directed by Curtis Hanson</p>
  <p>and the screenplay was written 
  by Peter Gould.The cast included William Hurt as Hank Paulson, the Treasury Secretary; 
  Paul Giamatti as Ben Bernanke, the chairman of the Federal Reserve; Billy Crudup as 
  Timothy Geithner; and Edward Asner as Warren Buffett.</p>
  <p><em>Too Big to Fail</em> won the 2010 Gerald Loeb Award for best business book of the year, 
  was a finalist for the 2010 <em>Financial Times</em> and Goldman Sachs Business Book of the Year 
  Award, and was on <em>The New York Times</em> Best Seller list (non-fiction hardcover and paperback) 
  for six months.</p>
  <p>Sorkin is a regular guest host of CNBC’s <em>Squawk Box</em> and appears frequently on MSNBC's 
  <em>Morning Joe</em>.  He has appeared on many other programs, including <em>Meet the Press</em>, 
  <em>Good Morning America</em>, <em>The Daily Show</em> with Jon Stewart, and <em>Charlie Rose</em>.</p>
  <p>Andrew Sorkin graduated from Scarsdale High School in 1995 and earned a Bachelor of Science 
  degree from Cornell University in 1999.  Additional accolades for Andrew Sorkin include winning a 
  Society of American Business Editors and Writers Award for breaking news in 2005 and again in 2006.  
  In 2007, the World Economic Forum named him a Young Global Leader.</p>
  <p><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>         
</article>
<h1><a id="chua">Babylon to Beijing: Risks and Rewards of Global Dominance</a></h1>     
<article>
  <img src="images/chua_220.jpg" alt="Amy Chua" width="145" />
  <h2>January<br>Amy Chua</h2>
  <p>Amy Chua joined the Yale faculty in 2001 after teaching at Duke Law School. 
  Prior to starting her teaching career, she was a corporate law associate at Cleary, Gottlieb, 
  Steen &amp; Hamilton. Her expertise is in international business transactions, law and 
  development, ethnic conflict, and globalization and the law.</p>
  <p>Born in Champaign, Illinois, Amy Chua's parents were ethnic Chinese from the Philippines 
  before immigrating to the United States. Amy's father, Leon O. Chua, is known as  father of 
  the nonlinear circuit theory and cellular neural networks. Amy Chua graduated magna cum laude 
  with an A. B. </p>
  <p>in Economics from Harvard College in 1984. 
  She obtained her J. D. cum laude in 1987 from Harvard Law School.</p>
  <p>Chua's first book, <em>World on Fire: How Exporting Free Market Democracy Breeds Ethnic 
  Hatred and Global Instability </em>was a <em>New York Times</em> bestseller, and was selected 
  by both <em>The Economist</em> and the U. K.'s <em>Guardian</em> as one the the Best Books of 
  2003. Her second book, <em>Day of Empire: How Hyperpowers Rise to Global Dominance- and Why 
  They Fall</em>, was a critically acclaimed Foreign Affairs bestseller.</p>
  <p>This Yale academic was catapulted into the public spotlight in 2011 with publication of 
  the<em> NY Times</em> bestseller, <em>Battle Hymn of the Tiger Mother</em>, a memoir 
  exploring strict parenting the &ldquo;Chinese Way&rdquo; as compared to more lenient western 
  parenting models.</p>
  <p><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>         
</article>
<h1><a id="sampson">Fossil Threads in the Web of Life</a></h1>
<article>
  <img src="images/sampson_dinosaur.jpg" alt="Scott Sampson">
  <h2>February<br>Scott Sampson</h2>
  <p>What's 75 million years old and brand spanking new? A teenage Utahceratops! Come to the Saroyan, 
  armed with your best dinosaur roar, when Scott Sampson, Research Curator at the Utah Museum of 
  Natural History, steps to the podium. Sampson's research has focused on the ecology and evolution 
  of late Cretaceous dinosaurs and he has conducted fieldwork in a number of countries in Africa.</p>
    <p>Scott Sampson is a Canadian-born paleontologist who received his Ph.D. in zoology from the 
    University of Toronto. His doctoral work focused on two new species of ceratopsids, or horned dinosaurs, 
    from the Late Cretaceous of Montana, as well as the growth and function of certopsid horns and frills.</p>
      <p>Following graduation in 1993, Sampson spent a year working at the American Museum of Natual History 
      in New York City, followed by five years as assistant professor of anatomy at the New York College of 
      Osteopathic Medicine on Long Island. He arrived at the University of Utah accepting a dual position as 
      assistant professor in the Department of Geology and Geophysics and curator of vertebrate paleontology 
      at the Utah Museum of Natural History. His research interests largely revolve around the phylogenetics, 
      functional morphology, and evolution of Late Cretaceous dinosaurs.</p>
      <p>In addition to his museum and laboratory-based studies, Sampson has conducted paleontological work 
      in Zimbabwe, South Africa, and Madagascar, as well as the United States and Canada. He was also the 
      on-the-air host for the Discovery Channel's Dinosaur Planet and recently completed a book, 
      <em>Dinosaur Odyssey: Fossil Threads in the Web of Life</em>, which is one of the most comprehensive 
      surveys of dinosaurs and their worlds to date.</p>
  <p><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>         
</article>

</section>
<aside>
<h1 id="speakers">This Year's Speakers</h1>
<nav id="nav_list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#toobin">October<br>Jeffrey Toobin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sorkin">November<br>Andrew Ross Sorkin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chua">January<br>Amy Chua</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sampson">February<br>Scott Sampson</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</aside>
```

Comment: Is all the text really necessary for reproducing the example?

Comment: Someone needs to visit https://www.lipsum.com/ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the obvious typo on `"id"`, your selector is wrong:

```
$("id").next("article").show();
```

Since the `id` targets the `a` element inside `h1` you have to go up first, for [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the sibling you seek:

```
$(id).parent().next("article").show();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split href value then it'll be same with id.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("article").hide();

  $("a").on("click", function() {
    href = $(this).attr("href");
    res = href.replace("#", "");
    if(href != res) {
      $("h1 a").hide();
      $("article").hide();
    }
    $(href).show();
    $(href).parent().next("article").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h1><a id="toobin">The Supreme Nine: Black Robed Secrets</a></h1>
  <article>
    
    <h2>October<br>Jeffrey Toobin</h2>
    <p>Author of the critically acclaimed best seller, The Nine: Inside the Secret World of the Supreme Court, Jeffrey Toobin brings the inside story of one of America's most mysterious and powerful institutions to the Saroyan stage. At the podium, Toobin
      is an unbiased, deeply analytic expert on American law, politics and procedure and he provides a unique look into the inner workings of the Supreme Court and its influence.</p>
    <p>Inside the Secret World of the Supreme Court was published by Doubleday and spent more than four months on the NY Times best-seller list, earning Toobin the 2008 J. Anthony Lukas Prize for Nonfiction from the Columbia Graduate School of Journalism.
      Toobin has also written several other best-selling books, including A Vast Conspiracy: The Real Story of the Sex Scandal that Nearly Brought Down a President; The Run of His Life: The People vs. O.J. Simpson; and Too Close to Call: The 36-Day Battle
      to Decide the 2000 Election.</p>
    <p>Jeffrey Toobin joined CBB from ABC News, where, during his six-year tenure as a legal analyst, he provided legal views on the nation's most provocative and high profile cases, including the O.J. Simpson civil trial and the Kenneth Starr investigation
      of the Clinton White House. Toobin received a 2001 Emmy Award for his coverage of the Elian Gonzales custody saga.</p>
    <p>Toobin is a staff writer at The New Yorker and has been covering legal affairs for the magazine since 1993. He has written articles on such subjects as Attorney General John Ashcroft, the 2001 dispute over Florida's votes for president, the Paula
      Jones sexual harassment case, and Supreme Court Justice Clarence Thomas.</p>
    <p>Currently a senior analyst for CNN Worldwide, Toobin is based in the network's New York bureau. He graduated from Harvard magna cum laude with a Bachelor of Arts degree in 1982 and earned a Truman scholarship. He is also a 1986 magna cum laude graduate
      of Harvard Law School, where he was an editor of the Harvard Law Review.</p>
    <p><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>
  </article>
  <h1><a id="sorkin">The Politics of <em>Too Big to Fail</em></a></h1>
  <article>
    
    <h2>November<br>Andrew Ross Sorkin</h2>
    <p><em>New York Times</em> columnist and author, Andrew Ross Sorkin, has been described as &ldquo;the most famous financial journalist of his generation.&rdquo; A leading voice on Wall Street and corporate America, his <em>New York Times</em> bestseller,
      <em>Too Big to Fail: The Inside Story of How Wall Street and Washington Fought to Save 
        the Financial System—and Themselves</em>, was the first true, behind-the-scenes, moment-by-moment account of how that financial crisis developed into a global tsunami.</p>
    <p><em>The Economist</em>, <em>The Financial Times</em> and <em>Business Week</em> all named
      <em>Too Big To Fail</em> one of the best books of the year. The book was published by Viking October 20, 2009. The book was adapted as a movie by HBO Films and premiered on HBO on May 23, 2011. The film was directed by Curtis Hanson</p>
    <p>and the screenplay was written by Peter Gould.The cast included William Hurt as Hank Paulson, the Treasury Secretary; Paul Giamatti as Ben Bernanke, the chairman of the Federal Reserve; Billy Crudup as Timothy Geithner; and Edward Asner as Warren
      Buffett.</p>
    <p><em>Too Big to Fail</em> won the 2010 Gerald Loeb Award for best business book of the year, was a finalist for the 2010 <em>Financial Times</em> and Goldman Sachs Business Book of the Year Award, and was on <em>The New York Times</em> Best Seller
      list (non-fiction hardcover and paperback) for six months.</p>
    <p>Sorkin is a regular guest host of CNBC’s <em>Squawk Box</em> and appears frequently on MSNBC's
      <em>Morning Joe</em>. He has appeared on many other programs, including <em>Meet the Press</em>,
      <em>Good Morning America</em>, <em>The Daily Show</em> with Jon Stewart, and <em>Charlie Rose</em>.</p>
    <p>Andrew Sorkin graduated from Scarsdale High School in 1995 and earned a Bachelor of Science degree from Cornell University in 1999. Additional accolades for Andrew Sorkin include winning a Society of American Business Editors and Writers Award for
      breaking news in 2005 and again in 2006. In 2007, the World Economic Forum named him a Young Global Leader.</p>
    <p><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>
  </article>
  <h1><a id="chua">Babylon to Beijing: Risks and Rewards of Global Dominance</a></h1>
  <article>
    
    <h2>January<br>Amy Chua</h2>
    <p>Amy Chua joined the Yale faculty in 2001 after teaching at Duke Law School. Prior to starting her teaching career, she was a corporate law associate at Cleary, Gottlieb, Steen &amp; Hamilton. Her expertise is in international business transactions,
      law and development, ethnic conflict, and globalization and the law.</p>
    <p>Born in Champaign, Illinois, Amy Chua's parents were ethnic Chinese from the Philippines before immigrating to the United States. Amy's father, Leon O. Chua, is known as father of the nonlinear circuit theory and cellular neural networks. Amy Chua
      graduated magna cum laude with an A. B. </p>
    <p>in Economics from Harvard College in 1984. She obtained her J. D. cum laude in 1987 from Harvard Law School.</p>
    <p>Chua's first book, <em>World on Fire: How Exporting Free Market Democracy Breeds Ethnic 
        Hatred and Global Instability </em>was a <em>New York Times</em> bestseller, and was selected by both <em>The Economist</em> and the U. K.'s <em>Guardian</em> as one the the Best Books of 2003. Her second book, <em>Day of Empire: How Hyperpowers Rise to Global Dominance- and Why 
        They Fall</em>, was a critically acclaimed Foreign Affairs bestseller.</p>
    <p>This Yale academic was catapulted into the public spotlight in 2011 with publication of the
      <em> NY Times</em> bestseller, <em>Battle Hymn of the Tiger Mother</em>, a memoir exploring strict parenting the &ldquo;Chinese Way&rdquo; as compared to more lenient western parenting models.</p>
    <p><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>
  </article>
  <h1><a id="sampson">Fossil Threads in the Web of Life</a></h1>
  <article>
    
    <h2>February<br>Scott Sampson</h2>
    <p>What's 75 million years old and brand spanking new? A teenage Utahceratops! Come to the Saroyan, armed with your best dinosaur roar, when Scott Sampson, Research Curator at the Utah Museum of Natural History, steps to the podium. Sampson's research
      has focused on the ecology and evolution of late Cretaceous dinosaurs and he has conducted fieldwork in a number of countries in Africa.</p>
    <p>Scott Sampson is a Canadian-born paleontologist who received his Ph.D. in zoology from the University of Toronto. His doctoral work focused on two new species of ceratopsids, or horned dinosaurs, from the Late Cretaceous of Montana, as well as the
      growth and function of certopsid horns and frills.</p>
    <p>Following graduation in 1993, Sampson spent a year working at the American Museum of Natual History in New York City, followed by five years as assistant professor of anatomy at the New York College of Osteopathic Medicine on Long Island. He arrived
      at the University of Utah accepting a dual position as assistant professor in the Department of Geology and Geophysics and curator of vertebrate paleontology at the Utah Museum of Natural History. His research interests largely revolve around the
      phylogenetics, functional morphology, and evolution of Late Cretaceous dinosaurs.</p>
    <p>In addition to his museum and laboratory-based studies, Sampson has conducted paleontological work in Zimbabwe, South Africa, and Madagascar, as well as the United States and Canada. He was also the on-the-air host for the Discovery Channel's Dinosaur
      Planet and recently completed a book,
      <em>Dinosaur Odyssey: Fossil Threads in the Web of Life</em>, which is one of the most comprehensive surveys of dinosaurs and their worlds to date.</p>
    <p><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>
  </article>

</section>
<aside>
  <h1 id="speakers">This Year's Speakers</h1>
  <nav id="nav_list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#toobin">October<br>Jeffrey Toobin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sorkin">November<br>Andrew Ross Sorkin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#chua">January<br>Amy Chua</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sampson">February<br>Scott Sampson</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```